# Skype bot ChatConnector: receive - invalid token

Tags: node.js, skype, botframework, ngrok

Good day.
I'm trying to build my first skype bot. 
Locally, using the Emulator, the bot responds fine.
But the problem is, as soon as i try to test it from the dashboard on Microsoft's web site, i do get the request, but in the console i get the following message

> ERROR: ChatConnector: receive - invalid token. Check bot's app ID & Password.

And no response is given to the client.

I've checked the validity of appId and password using the link from [here](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/support/troubleshooting-bot-framework-authentication/), second step, and i get the right response, so nothing wrong with that.

UPD: tried a couple of tunneling services, the problem is not the lack of a secure connection.

Still can't figure out what is the issue.